# How to enable powershell on azure web role?

Tags: powershell, azure, webrole

I want to remote PowerShell connection.

How to enable PowerShell on windows azure web role ?
...or, Is it possible ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something out..?

Comment: I want to use remote check log script...

Comment: Can you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196184/how-to-run-azure-cmdlets-from-a-powershell-script-in-a-published-web-role-vs2012) out if it helps you..?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable website diagnostic logging and then you can use Powershell CMDLets to save or get the latest parts of the log file. [How to enable Diagnostics Logging for Azure Web Sites](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/).

These are the cmdlets you'll need to use inside Powershell to get the log files from your website:

```
Get-AzureWebSiteLog -Name webappname -Tail
Save-AzureWebSiteLog -Name webappname
```